# In Linq, why doesn't ToList() take an optional predicate parameter to filter items?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a reason that the ToList method in the Linq library doesn't provide an optional predicate parameter that filters the collection before generating a new list?  The signature for such a call would be:

```
//---------------------------------VVVVVV
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

With this, in the same way that these two `Count` calls have the same effect:

```
var c1 = items.Where(i => i > 2).Count();
var c2 = items.Count(i => i > 2);
```

These two `ToList` calls would have the same effect:

```
var list1 = items.Where(i => i > 2).ToList();
var list2 = items.ToList(i => i > 2);
```

I'm wondering if this was left out on purpose.

Edit: for those voting to put this on-hold as opinion-based, I'm not looking for an opinion-based answer.  I'm wondering if it's ever specifically been addressed by the designers.  [Here's a designer explaining why C# doesn't have top-level methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/).  I'd like to know if there's something similar for this.

Comment: Because you can easily create your own? Or just use `Where(...).ToList()`? Basically, most of those questions can simply be answered by "because no-one ever felt it was neccessary and thus no-one implemented it".

Comment: I actually wonder why there is overload for `Count` which accepts predicate - not best sample of SRP

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy When I first started with C# in 2015, it took me by surprise months later that I could use an overload of `Count` instead of using `x.Where(predicate).Count()` which looks more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would `ToList` accept a *filter*? Why wouldn’t it accept a selector like [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) does? Why not [a group selector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx)?

Why should the two things be equivalent:

```
items.Where(i => i > 2).ToList()
items.ToList(i => i > 2);
```

Why couldn’t it be this?

```
items.Select(i => i * 2).ToList()
items.ToList(i => i * 2);
```

---

I hope you get what I’m trying to say here. There are *a lot* of different ways to generate data using LINQ. LINQ is all about chaining modular methods to suit the need you have and usually don’t come with too many opinions. Adding a selector to `ToList` would conflict with that idea.

Comment: Good point about unclear meaning of delegate which would be passed to `ToList`

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this confusion doesn't exist with `Count` as we know that it will return an `int`

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons I can think of is that in most cases `.ToList()` will actually execute the query against the database and it's usually best to have it the last call in your LINQ chain because you want to execute the query only once.

If you are using LINQ to objects then is because the desing of LINQ is to have composable queries on collections of objects. The extension method `.ToList()` is used to convert the computed filters (query) into a collection of objects that you can use.